# How to make rp and xrange dynamic?

Tags: python, xml, dynamic, web-scraping, xrange

Hey guys many thanks for taking the time to look at my problem, I have been working on this code for about 1 week (I am new to coding and to python 1 week also) Currently the loop only works if x in xrange(x) and 'rp' : 'x' is the correct number of rows available from this xml. The xml updates throughout the day, I was wondering if anyone can offer a solution to make x dynamic?

```
import mechanize
import urllib
import json
import re
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep

from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep

s = scheduler(time, sleep)

def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
event_time = start
while event_time < end:
    s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
    event_time += interval
s.run()

def getData():  
post_url = "urlofinterest_xml"
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

######These are the parameters you've got from checking with the aforementioned tools
parameters = {'page' : '1',
              'rp' : '8',
              'sortname' : 'roi',
              'sortorder' : 'desc'
             }
#####Encode the parameters
data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
trans_array = browser.open(post_url,data).read().decode('UTF-8')

xmlload1 = json.loads(trans_array)
pattern1 = re.compile('>&nbsp;&nbsp;(.*)<')
pattern2 = re.compile('/control/profile/view/(.*)\' title=')
pattern3 = re.compile('<span style=\'font-size:12px;\'>(.*)<\/span>')
pattern4 = re.compile('title=\'Naps posted: (.*) Winners:')
pattern5 = re.compile('Winners: (.*)\'><img src=')


for i in xrange(8):
    user_delimiter = xmlload1['rows'][i]['cell']['username']
    selection_delimiter = xmlload1['rows'][i]['cell']['race_horse']

    username_delimiter_results = re.findall(pattern1, user_delimiter)[0]
    userid_delimiter_results = int(re.findall(pattern2, user_delimiter)[0])
    user_selection = re.findall(pattern3, selection_delimiter)[0]
    user_numberofselections = float(re.findall(pattern4, user_delimiter)[0])
    user_numberofwinners = float(re.findall(pattern5, user_delimiter)[0])

    strikeratecalc1 = user_numberofwinners/user_numberofselections
    strikeratecalc2 = strikeratecalc1*100

    print "user id = ",userid_delimiter_results
    print "username = ",username_delimiter_results
    print "user selection = ",user_selection
    print "best price available as decimal = ",xmlload1['rows'][i]['cell']     ['tws.best_price']
    print "race time = ",xmlload1['rows'][i]['cell']['race_time']
    print "race meeting = ",xmlload1['rows'][i]['cell']['race_meeting']
    print "ROI = ",xmlload1['rows'][i]['cell']['roi']
    print "number of selections = ",user_numberofselections
    print "number of winners = ",user_numberofwinners
    print "Strike rate = ",strikeratecalc2,"%"
    print ""


getData()


run_periodically(time()+5, time()+1000000, 15, getData)
```

Kind regards AEA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'm going to talk about how you iterate over your results. Based on your code, `xmlload1['rows']` is an array of dicts, so instead of choosing an arbitrary number, you can iterate over it directly instead.  To make this a better example, I'm going to set up some arbitrary data to make this clear:

```
xmlload1 = {
   "rows": [{"cell": {"username": "one", "race_horse":"b"}}, {"cell": {"username": "two", "race_horse": "c"}}]
}
```

So, given the data above, you can just iterate through rows in a for loop, like this:

```
for row in xmlload1['rows']:
    cell = row["cell"]
    print cell["username"]
    print cell["race_horse"]
```

Each iteration, cell takes on the value of another element in the iterable (the list in `xmlload1['rows']`). This works with any container or sequence that supports iteration (like `lists`, `tuples`, `dicts`, `generators`, etc.)

Notice how I haven't used any magic numbers anywhere, so `xmlload1['rows']` could be arbitrarily long and it would still work.

You can set the requests to be dynamic by using a function, like this:

```
def get_data(rp=8, page=1):
    parameters = {'page' : str(page),
              'rp' : str(rp),
              'sortname' : 'roi',
              'sortorder' : 'desc'
             }
    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
    trans_array = browser.open(post_url,data).read().decode('UTF-8')
    return json.loads(trans_array)
```

Now, you can call `get_data(rp=5)` to get 5 rows, or `get_data(rp=8)` to get 8 rows [and `get_data(rp=8, page=3)` to get the third page], etc.  And you can clearly add additional variables or even pass in the `parameters` dict to the function directly.

Comment: Hey Jeff, first of all many thanks for answering the question, and even more points for making it like a lesson, explaining your answer fully. If my interpretation is correct i need to define what a row is (clarification? ) as you have with : `xmlload1 = {
   "rows": [{"cell": {"username": "one", "race_horse":"b"}}, {"cell": {"username": "two", "race_horse": "c"}}] }`

Comment: @AEA you don't need to define what a row is, based on your code, that's the structure of the data that your query generates. Add a `print xmlload1` to your code after the line with `json.loads` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: An example of the xml i am reading : ``{u'cell': {u'username': u'<a onclick=\'newPopup(this.href,"big"); return false\' href=\'/control/profile/view/2419\' title=\'Naps posted: 2 Winners: 1\'><img src=\'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3627783463/de40c26fd167a1306730e1721448921a_normal.jpeg\'  style=\'width:22px; height:22px;\' />&nbsp;&nbsp;RobLloyd91</a>', u'roi': u'18 to go', u'race_time': u'16:15',` How would I define this (please note I may use the incorrect jargon regularly at the moment. Still learning)

Comment: Hi thanks for your prompt reply! I hadn't even finished adding the second part of the question.

Comment: Is it acceptable to put pastebin links in comments to overcome character limit? Cureently I have tried very simply to run the following `xmlload1 = {"rows": [{"cell": {"username": "one", "race_horse":"b"}}, {"cell": {"username": "two", "race_horse": "c"}}]}

    for cell in xmlload1['rows']:
    
        print cell['username']` It is returning a key error. I have currently left the request as this `parameters = {'page' : '1',
                  'rp' : '250',
                  'sortname' : 'roi',
                  'sortorder' : 'desc'
                 }` Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @AEA I made a mistake. You need to get to the "cell" part of the dictionary, I'll fix my example too. If you look back at the example, you can see how to do it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I actually like it when the established coders make a mistake shows me they are actually human :)

Comment: From the information kindly supplied by Jeff I managed to fix the problem at hand kudos!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think what you want is this:

```
rows = xmlload1['rows']
for row in rows:
    user_delimiter = row['cell']['username']
    selection_delimiter = row['cell']['race_horse']
    # ...
```

If you need the row index as well as the row itself, use `enumerate`:

```
rows = xmlload1['rows']
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    user_delimiter = row['cell']['username']
    selection_delimiter = row['cell']['race_horse']
    # ...
```

In general, if you're doing `for i in range(…)` for any purpose other than a fixed number of iterations, you're doing it wrong. There's usually a collection you want to iterate over; just find it and iterate over it.